syntax error near unexpected token `$argv[1]'
I am writing a automation script to execute ptpx.
There are 2 files.
run_power.cmd has shebang #!/usr/sachin/bin/tcsh, inside this file one more file is being sourced, vars.cmd and it doesn't have any shebang.
When I source it from Python, I get the following error
vars.cmd: line 23: syntax error near unexpected token `$argv[1]'
vars.cmd: line 23: `    switch ($argv[1])'

run_power.cmd: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `exit'

in run_power.cmd
line3:## source variables 
line4: source vars.cmd
iline5: f ( $1 == "-help" || $1 == "--help" || $1 == "-h" || $1 == "--h" ) exit 0
line6: 
line 7: echo '--------------------------------------------------------------' 

in vars.cmd
line 22: set CMD_HELP = '\n Available User Controls: \n\t-abc con.abc" \n\t-scenarios "max_nom" \n\t-up_tag "24ww20" \n\t-top_autofixer_vars "t-sis2sis "24ww15" \n\t-qp_version "15.25" \n\t-tests "t4," \n\t-test_script "t3" \n'
line23:while ( $#argv != 0 )
line24:  switch ($argv[1])
line25: case "-help": 

python file content
final_power_cmd = f'source {path}/run_power.cmd -abc {abc} -test {test} >> {log_file} & ' 
print(final_power_cmd)
os.system(final_power_cmd)

Can please anyone guess what I am doing wrong here?

os.system() uses /bin/sh, no matter which shell the user has configured as their account default -- so csh or tcsh syntax isn't legal there.

Separately, using string concatenation to build content executed as code is how shell injection attacks happen. Don't do that.

(To spell things out a little further: Because source runs a script in the preexisting shell process, it doesn't honor shebangs)

@CharlesDuffy can you please help me with detail answer ?

tcsh stopped being popular around 1990 for very good reasons. You'll probably be better off writing a simple POSIX shell script.

A minimal fix is probably to replace source ... in the Python script with tcsh -c '...'; you'll then need to switch the Python quoting to double quotes.

A better fix would be to replace os.system() with subprocess.run([f'{path}/run_power.cmd', '-abc', abc, '-test', test], stdout=open(log_file, 'a'))

os.system() uses /bin/sh, which can't run tcsh code. (It also isn't guaranteed to support source at all -- likely your /bin/sh is provided by bash, as the POSIX equivalent to source is .).
A bigger concern here is that the current code is subject to shell injection attacks -- if a user specifies an abc value of $(rm -rf ~), you're going to have your home directory deleted. Both of these can be avoided by executing the script as a subprocess rather than sourcing it, and invoking it with an explicit argument vector.
subprocess.run(
    [f'{path}/run_power.cmd', '-abc', abc, '-test', test],
    stdout=open(log_file, 'a')
)

This does require your run_power.cmd to have +x permissions (in addition to the shebang you've already shown us it has), but that's par for the course.
